# how to implement windows service loop that waits for a period in C# / .NET2.0

Tags: c#, windows-services

My question is that is this the best practice to do this. Couldn't find any good examples. I have following code in file created by VS2005:

```
public partial class ObjectFolder : ServiceBase
{
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        ObjectFolderApp.Initialize();

        ObjectFolderApp.StartMonitorAndWork();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // TODO: Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop yourservice.
    } 
}
```

then:

```
class ObjectFolderApp
{
    public static bool Initialize()
    {
        //all init stuff
        return true;
    }


    public static void StartMonitorAndWork()
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread(MonitorAndWork);
        worker.Start();
    }


    private static void MonitorAndWork()
    {
        int loopTime = 60000;
        if (int.TryParse(_cfgValues.GetConfigValue("OfWaitLoop"), out loopTime))
            loopTime = 1000 * loopTime;

        while (true)
        {
            /* create+open connection and fill DataSet */
            DataSet ofDataSet = new DataSet("ObjectFolderSet");
            using (_cnctn = _dbFactory.CreateConnection())
            {
                _cnctn.Open();

                //do all kinds of database stuff
            }
            Thread.Sleep(loopTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Re-hashing my answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405619/thread-sleep-and-windows-services/2405930#2405930), the recommended way is to use a timer and the following code:

```
public class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    private Timer workTimer;    // System.Threading.Timer

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        workTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(DoWork), null, 5000, 5000);
        base.OnStart(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        workTimer.Dispose();
        base.OnStop();
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        RunScheduledTasks();  // Do some work
    }
}
```

Simple!

Note that the `Timer` type being used is `System.Threading.Timer`, same as [Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593583/how-to-implement-windows-service-loop-that-waits-for-a-period-in-c-net2-0/2593596#2593596) specifies.

Comment: The above code works like a charm. I'm using in a windows service to check a queue.

Comment: thanks!  ...hmmm... so you suggest I don't even call ObjectFolderApp.Initialize();
in OnStart?? It has to be initialized only once. Another question is calling overrided base methods. Why is that?

Comment: @matti: I don't know what you're doing in `Initialize`, so it's hard to say. You might still need it. As for calling the base methods, you don't necessarily have to, but as a general rule it's a good idea if what you're trying to do is *extend* the base class logic as opposed to *replace* it (which is the desired semantic here).

Comment: Initialize is for reading configuration file etc. the normal init tasks.

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441368/prevent-multiple-instance-of-a-service-best-approach handles the situation where the action takes longer then the interval

Answer (score 3):

Use a [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) to fire the process off at the scheduled interval.