# Synchronize Timer with real time

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I am trying to refresh my frame every `17ms` with a `timer`.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(17);
timer.Elapsed += ResetFrame;
timer.Start();
```

But instead of waiting for `17ms` and then repeating, it waited for the frame refresh to complete and then wait for `17ms`for the next repeat. This causes the frame to be refreshed every `28ms`. How to synchronize it with real time?

Comment: Your UI thread is busy executing your handler (which refreshes the frame I assume). How is it going to keep executing your handler and start executing it again too, all at the same time? You could have an [async handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39260486/11683), but I doubt the result will be what you expect it to be.

Comment: 17ms is delay between end of previous handler and start of next, not a delay from start to start i guess.

Comment: @aepot [Not really](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10471354/11683).

Comment: [Timer accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228313/most-accurate-timer-in-net)

Comment: What `Timer` do you use ? From what namespace ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier I'm using `System.Timers`;

Comment: Have you tried the timer in `System.Threading` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer

Comment: Found that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228313/most-accurate-timer-in-net & http://ideveloper-dotnet.blogspot.com/2013/07/real-time-timer-in-c.html & https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98346/Microsecond-and-Millisecond-NET-Timer & https://github.com/SunsetQuest/Precision-Repeat-Action-On-Interval-Async-Method/blob/master/Program.cs

Comment: @OlivierRogier The code of the https://ideveloper-dotnet.blogspot.com/2013/07/real-time-timer-in-c.html solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a real time timer having a very short interval, you can take a look at this article:

[Real Time Timer in C#](http://ideveloper-dotnet.blogspot.com/2013/07/real-time-timer-in-c.html)

> In  Dot Net, following timers are not real time.
>
> `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`
> `System.Timers.Timer`
> `System.Threading.Timer`
>
> Means if you want to run your code at every 100 millisecond then above
> timer fire even around 110 millisecond or later. Windows is not a real
> time OS because of this .Net is also not a real time.
>
> To create a real time timer in C# you have to write custom code that
> can hold CPU to run your code at right time.

```cs
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Running");
    RealTimeTimerTest obj = new RealTimeTimerTest();
 
    obj.Run();
  }
}
 
public class RealTimeTimerTest
{
   List<DateTime> lst = new List<DateTime>();
  System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
 
  public void Run()
  {
    int Tick = 100;
    int Sleep = Tick - 20;
    long OldElapsedMilliseconds = 0;
    sw.Start();

    while (sw.IsRunning)
    {
      long ElapsedMilliseconds = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
      long mod = (ElapsedMilliseconds % Tick);

      if (OldElapsedMilliseconds != ElapsedMilliseconds && (mod == 0 || ElapsedMilliseconds > Tick))
      {

        //-----------------Do here whatever you want to do--------------Start
        lst.Add(DateTime.Now);
        //-----------------Do here whatever you want to do--------------End

        //-----------------Restart----------------Start
        OldElapsedMilliseconds = ElapsedMilliseconds;
        OldElapsedMilliseconds = 0;
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
 
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Sleep); 
         //-----------------Restart----------------End
      }
       
      //------------Must define some condition to break the loop here-----------Start

      if (lst.Count > 500)
      {
        Write();
        break;
      }
      //-------------Must define some condition to break the loop here-----------End
    }
  }

 
  private void Write()
  {
    System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("d:\\text.txt", true);
    foreach (DateTime dtStart in lst)
      sw.WriteLine(dtStart.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff"));    sw.Close();
  }
}
```

Also that:

[Most accurate timer in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228313/most-accurate-timer-in-net)

[High resolution timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137121/high-resolution-timer)

[High resolution timer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839105/high-resolution-timer-in-c-sharp)

[Microsecond and Millisecond C# Timer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98346/Microsecond-and-Millisecond-NET-Timer)

[Precision-Repeat-Action-On-Interval-Async-Method](https://github.com/SunsetQuest/Precision-Repeat-Action-On-Interval-Async-Method/blob/master/Program.cs)